# Java Generic relating to base and child class "not applicable for the arguments"

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, extends

I did found come similar looking posts on generic issues, but non of them captured my problem in a way I could understand it. I hope someone can help me with this case.

I tried lots of things like removing the "? extends" from different places and playing with "? super" to see if another error would point me in a direction of a solutions.

The following code:

```
final ResponseBase response = executor.execute(myRequest);
```

Gives me the following compiler error:
"The method execute(capture#6-of ? extends RequestBase) in the type CommandExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (RequestBase)"

The complete code listing:

```
public class MainClass {

    private final static Map<Class<? extends RequestBase>, CommandExecutor<? extends RequestBase, ? extends ResponseBase>> MAP = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final DummyCommandExecutor dummyCommandExecutor = new DummyCommandExecutor();
        MAP.put(MyRequest.class, dummyCommandExecutor);

        final RequestBase myRequest = new MyRequest();
        myRequest.setRequestString("this is my request");

        final CommandExecutor<? extends RequestBase, ? extends ResponseBase> executor = MAP.get(myRequest.getClass());

        final ResponseBase response = executor.execute(myRequest);

        System.out.println(response.getResponseString());
    }
}

interface CommandExecutor<T, R> {

    R execute(T object);

}

class DummyCommandExecutor implements CommandExecutor<MyRequest, MyResponse> {

    @Override
    public MyResponse execute(MyRequest request) {

        final MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
        response.setResponseString(request.getRequestString());

        return response;
    }

}

class MyResponse extends ResponseBase {

}

class ResponseBase {
    String responseString;

    public String getResponseString() {
        return this.responseString;
    }

    public void setResponseString(String responseString) {
        this.responseString = responseString;
    }
}

class MyRequest extends RequestBase {

}

class RequestBase {
    String requestString;

    public String getRequestString() {
        return this.requestString;
    }

    public void setRequestString(String requestString) {
        this.requestString = requestString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without casting. While you know that the map will return the correct command executor for a given type, the compiler does not, so you need to tell the compiler to not care:

```
final CommandExecutor<RequestBase,ResponseBase> executor = (CommandExecutor) MAP.get(myRequest.getClass());
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Still not sure why the compiler doesn't know. The compiler should know that the HashMap contains a value of "CommandExecutor<? extends RequestBase, ? extends ResponseBase>"

Comment: The problem is `?` could be any class that extends `RequestBase` - The compiler doesn't know that the `? extends RequestBase` in the key of the map is always the same as the `? extends RequestBase` in the returned CommandExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot just match ? with T

an option is just to do :

```
final CommandExecutor executor = MAP.get(myRequest.getClass());
```

in which option of course you can get run time exception if the map returns smth not castable